# Shorttoc and Hyperref

Tags: hyperref, shorttoc

I want to print the table of content create in a first file (called **Ch1_Essai.tex**)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}

\end{document}
```

in a second file (called **Essai.tex**)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}

\begin{document}
 \anothertableofcontents{Ch1_Essai}{}{3}
\end{document}
```

using the package **shorttoc**.

Without **hyperref** in the first file (Ch1_Essai.tex), the compilation of the second file (Essai.tex) works great. But hyperref (in Ch1_Essai.tex) modifies the file format of Ch1_Essai.toc and this seems to make it unusable by shorttoc.

What should I do to keep the .toc file in a format usable by shorttoc ?

Thanks !

Comment: unrelated but don't use \usepackage{ae,aecompl}, that is really not needed in a current tex system if you have cm-super installed.

Comment: Why don't you load hyperref in both documents? That would be the easiest.

Comment: Of course, yes ! It solved my problem. How didn't I think to this before ?

Thanks !

Comment: thinking about it you could get wrong links in your shorttoc, so better surround it by a NoHyper environment.

Comment: Yes indeed : it is now perfect.
Thank you !